# Android App that pulls Information from URL (IMDB)

Tags: android, parsing, pull, imdb

I want to add a tab to my Android App that pulls information from the web. The first tab should be a list of the most popular TV Shows on IMDB (http://www.imdb.com/search/title?at=0&count=100&sort=moviemeter&title_type=tv_series,mini_series) for example.

What would be my first steps? How can I parse this data and then reuse (the title for example) in my app? I am not really familiar with API and parsing data, so I need some guidance towards the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Jsoup](http://www.jsoup.org) for parsing html data.

Include jsoup in your app by configuring the build path.

Jsoup is so easy to use and parse data

The jsoup website itself is very helpful for its usage.

For easy parsing of the website first understand the source of site and use the [Online Jsoup Parser](http://try.jsoup.org)